# handle events in flask before they propagate to more specific approutes

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have a flask app. Occasionally, it might be common to come across a series of routes like so, which are very related (code not tested, just to demonstrate a point):

```
@app.route('/stats/charts/count/<attribute>', methods=['GET'])
def count_attribute(attribute):
  counter = collections.Counter()
  for x in csv_mod.data:
    counter[attribute] += 1
  return counter

@app.route('/stats/charts/filter/<attribute>/<value>', methods=['GET'])
def filter_attribute(attribute, value):
  filtered = []
  for entry in csv_mod.data:
    if getattr(entry, attribute) != value:
      filtered.append(entry)
  return filtered
```

now let's say there's also a way in which they can input a query parameter which will split the data. Eg, they put in `03` in the request or something. Before visiting any of the `/stats/charts` app routes, I would like a "gatekeeper" method to cut this data before doing the approute, without explicitly stating to run this method in every method under `/stats/charts/`

```
@app.route('/stats/charts/*', methods=['GET']) # any route with this base
def cut_data():
  month = request.args.get('month', None)
  if month is None: 
    #propagate to the specific approute
  else:
    # cut data and then go to the specific approute
```

Now, if they visit `:site:/stats/charts/count/crows/` with `03` in the request, it would know to cut the data correctly before proceeding to the "actual" approute. Would there be a way to add a generic method like that across a series of methods? What would be the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it a decorator; views are just functions, and a decorator can add additional arguments to your function:

```
from functools import wraps

def cut_data(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        month = request.args.get('month', None)
        if month is None:
            # redirect to same endpoint with new query parameter
            return redirect(request.endpoint, month='some month', **request.view_args)

        # cut data
        data = some_magic(csv_mod.data, month)
        # call actual view function
        return func(data=data, *args, **kw)

    return wrapper
```

then use with your routes:

```
@app.route('/stats/charts/count/<attribute>', methods=['GET'])
@cut_data
def count_attribute(attribute, data=None):
    counter = collections.Counter()
    for x in data:
        counter[attribute] += 1
    return counter

@app.route('/stats/charts/filter/<attribute>/<value>', methods=['GET'])
@cut_data
def filter_attribute(attribute, value, data=None):
    filtered = []
    for entry in data:
        if getattr(entry, attribute) != value:
            filtered.append(entry)
    return filtered
```

and the wrapper will be called by Flask and can call the actual view function with an extra keyword parameter `data`, with the data pre-cut for the month.